# Are Gamecube discs the same size as standard mini-dvds?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

Recently, the number of game cases on my shelf has gotten to the point that it's becoming inconvenient to go through them to find games, so I've recently been moving away from using the original cases, going for the cases that can hold a ton of games.

For most consoles, this isn't a problem, as they fit the standard cd cases you find everywhere, which can usually hold up to about 120 discs.

However, the smaller size of GameCube discs make them more of a pain. While they (obviously) fit in the sleeves designed for full size discs, they don't stay in place very well and are likely to fall out, so I was trying to find something for them.

I found some marketed specifically toward GameCube games, but I also found some that are for MiniCD and MiniDVD. Are they the same size (or near enough to the same size that their sleeves would fit)?

If anyone has any experience in this, I'd appreciate it.

(Also, the relationship of this question to gaming is, admittedly, tenuous at best, so if somewhere more appropriate for this question, let me know.)

Comment: The discs themselves are smaller, but the cases they come in are roughly the same size as PS2 cases.

Comment: I'm concerned about the discs themselves, as I'm wondering about the cd sleeves (I think that's what they're called).

Comment: Re: relationship to gaming, I think you're okay. I don't see why this should be off-topic.  You're asking about game-disc storage.

Comment: Don't throw out your cases if you want to sell some games they will be worth more with the case

Comment: I would never throw out my cases (or realistically, sell my games). This is just so I don't have to go through a huge awkward pile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gamecube CDs have the same diameter as MiniCD/DVD (which is 80mm).

A sleeve for MiniCD/DVD should also fit a Gamecube CD.

Soruces:

[Wikipedia MiniDVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiniDVD)

[Wikipedia Nintendo optical discs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_optical_discs)